# How to make idempotent taking a reference to a dereference of an iterator

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, dereference

The code bellow (-std=c++11) according to a "naive" view should work. 
Instead it doesn't (should be known and understood why it doesn't).
Which is the shortest way of modifying the code (overloading &) in order to make it behave according to the "naive" view ? 
Shouldn't that be given as an option during stl object creation (without writting too much) ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   std::vector<int> A{10,20,30};
    auto i=A.begin();
    auto j=&*i;
    std::cout<<"i==j gives "<<(i==j)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is your actual goal? At which point would you want that behaviour to be valid?

Comment: Yes.  *Why* would you want to break the "convert to actual address" operator (&*).

Comment: explain what you mean by "work"

Comment: @MartinBonner I mean that I would like to have &*i equivalent to i

Comment: Yes, but that means the result of &* won't be a raw pointer - which I regard as "breaking" the "raw address operator".  (There is now a standard function which returns the raw address operator, even in the presence of `operator &` - but I regard it as very poor taste to stop &* working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem cannot be solved.  There are *three* reasons it cannot be solved.

**First problem**

The `operator &` you need to overload is the `operator &` for the element type of the vector.  You cannot overload `operator &` for arbitrary types, and in particular you can't overload it for built-in types (like `int` in your example).

**Second problem**

Presumably you want this to work for `std::vector`, `std::array`, and built-in arrays?  Also probably `std::list`, `std::deque`, etc?  You can't.  The iterators for each of those contains will be different (in practise:  in *theory*, some of them could share iterators, but I am not aware of any standard library where they do.)

**Third problem**

If you were prepared to accept that this would only work for `std::vector<MyType>`, then you could overload `MyType::operator &` - but you still couldn't work out which `std::vector<MyType>` the `MyType` object lives in (and you need that to obtain the iterator).

Comment: Regarding First problem the approach isn't exact. What should be overloaded is operator & for a reference to int ( it is important to be a reference because if it isn't obviously we cannot get the iterator ). Regarding the overload of & for built in types I suppose you are correct, so the problem should be modified having instead of int a struct in order to be able to do it.

Comment: Regarding second problem, a reference to object may be converted to an iterator easilly for a random access container. Instead for a non random access one, the operation is slow.

Comment: Regarding the third problem, you are correct. We may convert a reference to an iterator only in the case where both references and iterators are implemented as pointers. This on the other side is the case in usual implementations.

Comment: But there is to say something more that I don't really understand actually: iterators have the possibility to define the type of the value, the type of the pointer to the value, and the type of the reference. So may be defining them in different ways it is still possible to obtain the desired effect.

Comment: And we could also overload the assignement operator for the reference_type. But how exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

First of, in your code snippet `i` deducts to `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `j` deducts to `int*`. The compiler doesn't know how to compare `std::vector<int>::iterator` against `int*`.

For this to work out, you could provide an overloaded `operator==` that would compare vector iterators against vector value type pointers in the following manner:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(typename std::vector<T>::iterator it, T *i) {
  return &(*it) == i;
}

template<typename T>
bool operator==(T *i, typename std::vector<T>::iterator it) {
  return it == i;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/807ff046bef10285)

Comment: This compares the addresses of the element for equality rather than the element itself. I borrowed your idea below but dereferenced the pointer and iterator. Hope that is ok etiquette.

Comment: @T33C perhaps OP wants to compare addresses rather than values, (this is different if vector contains multiple copies of the same value)

Comment: Perhaps... but strange thing to do especially with a container which might relocate its elements when more are added and it needs to resize.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't work - not even "accoding to a 'naive"' view". Eventhough every pointer is an iterator the reverse is not necessarily true. Why would you expect that to work?

It would work under two scenarios:

1. The `iterator` of the `std::vector<T>` implementation is actually a `T*`. Then your code would work since `decltype(i) == int*` and `decltype(j) == int*)`. This MAY be the case for some compilers but you shouldn't even rely on it if it was true for your compiler.
2. The dereference operator does not return an object of type `T` but rather something that is convertible to `T` and has an overloaded `operator&` which gives the iterator back. This is not the case for very good reasons.

You could -as other have suggested- overload `operator==` to check whether both indirections (pointer and iterator) reference the same object but I suspect that you want the address of operator to give you back the iterator which cannot be accomplished if the iterator is not a pointer because the object type which is stored in the vector has no notion of vector/iterator or whatever.

> The problem isn't in the equality operator, what I need is to define the dereference operator to give an iterator

You can't. The dereference operator in question is `std::vector<int>::iterator` which is part of the standard library and you can (and should not) manipulate it.

---

Note that since C++11 in a `std::vector<T, A>`,

- `value_type` is `T` and
- `reference` is `T&`.

Furthermore, the following is true:

- All *input iterators* **`i`** support **`*i`** which gives a value of type `T` which is the *value type* of that iterator.
- The iterator of `std::vector<T>` is required to have `T` as its *value type*.
- An iterator of `std::vector<T>` is an *input iterator*.

Comment: The template std::vector has many arguments besides the first one. These are available in order to be given. So I am looking for any solution that may give the requested behaviour.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: As I asked below your question: Why would you want to do that? ... One `std:vector` template argument is just the element type, the other is about the allocation. The second one does not affect the behaviour you intend to change. You COULD work round the problem by wrapping your actual type in a type which stores a pointer to the vector it is stored in and once initialized uses `operator&` to give you the proper iterator but that would not be very useful.

Comment: The member that is about the allocation, specifies al lot of things as value_type, pointer, reference, I suppose with that is possible to obtain the result.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: No it does not and no it is not.